# Nestjs test e2e ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: nestjs, e2e-testing

I am having the error `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80` when running a test e2e with Nestjs to test a dto.

Here is my code:

```
const TEST_URL = 'test';

@Controller(TEST_URL)
class TestController {
  @Post()
  public test(@Body() param: TimeTableParam) {
    // nothing
  }
}

describe('TimeTableParam', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [TestController],
    }).compile();

    app = module.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  describe('...', () => {
    it(`should ...`, () => {
      //...
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The fix was really simple but hard to find. Thanks to this [thread](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/3960) this is what I did:

```
const TEST_URL = '/test';
                  ^ add a '/'
```

Comment: Thanks. That would have taken a long time for me to figure out!